# Using tweenr and gganimate with a Static Map

Tags: r, tween, gganimate

I have a general question. I'm super new to using these packages, and am not incredibly r savvy, so apologies in advance! I am trying to make a static map which has points on it. I would like to animate the map using both tweenr and gganimate to have the points on the map smoothly grow and shrink depending on another variable within the dataset.

Most of the examples I'm finding using tweenr and gganimate are for plots/graphs and not for maps. I have been animating my maps using transition_time, but I can't decide which tweenr function to use.

Does anyone have any recommendations, or could someone point me in the right direction to find some applicable examples?

Thanks!

Also:
In the code I have below, you can see the points bounce back and forth between each other/leave trails. I don't want that, I just want the static points to grow and shrink. Any advice to fix that?

Here is some code I have tested:

```
map.zoomB<-ggplot(data = na.lakes, aes(x = long, y = lat)) + 
  geom_polygon(data = na.map, aes(long, lat, group = group),
               colour = "grey", fill="grey98") + 
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group), colour = "grey",
               fill = "white") + coord_map(projection
               ="mercator",xlim = c(xminA, xmaxA), ylim =
                 c(yminA, ymaxA)) + labs(x = "", y = "") +
  geom_point(aes(x = recvLon, y = recvLat, 
            size=detectperhour),
             data = year2018.B,
              alpha=.5) +
  labs(size = 'Daily Detections per Hour Tower Functional')+
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(1, 5), 
                        breaks = c(10, 50, 100, 500,1000)) +
  theme_bw() 

map.zoomB
```

```
combine.map.B <-map.zoomB +
  geom_point(data = year2018.B, aes(x = recvLon, y = recvLat, size = detectperhour), alpha = .2) +
  labs(title= "Number of Detections at Each Tower in Atlantic Canada Strat B", subtitle = "Date: {frame_time}", x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") 


combine.map.B
```

```
animate.map.B<- combine.map.B +
  transition_time(Date) +
  enter_appear() +
  shadow_mark(alpha = 0.3, size = 1) 


animate.map.B

map.B.final<-animate(animate.map.B,
                     duration = 90,
                     fps = 20,
                     end_pause = 10)
```

here's data:

```
structure(list(Age = c("Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", 
"Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", 
"Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", 
"Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", 
"Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", 
"Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", 
"Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", 
"Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", 
"Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", 
"Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", 
"Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", 
"Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", "Juvenile", 
"Juvenile", "Juvenile"), doy = c(224L, 224L, 226L, 226L, 227L, 
227L, 228L, 228L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 
229L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 230L, 230L, 230L, 231L, 231L, 
231L, 232L, 232L, 232L, 232L, 233L, 233L, 233L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 
235L, 235L, 236L, 236L, 237L, 237L, 238L, 238L, 239L, 239L, 240L, 
240L, 241L, 241L, 242L, 242L, 242L, 243L, 243L, 243L, 243L, 243L, 
243L, 243L, 243L, 243L, 243L, 244L, 244L, 245L, 245L, 246L, 246L, 
247L, 247L, 247L, 247L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 250L, 252L, 229L, 229L, 
230L, 230L, 231L, 231L, 232L, 232L, 233L, 233L, 234L, 234L, 235L, 
235L, 236L, 236L, 237L, 237L, 238L, 238L, 239L, 239L, 240L, 240L, 
241L, 241L, 242L, 242L, 242L, 243L, 243L, 243L, 243L, 243L, 243L, 
244L, 244L, 244L, 245L, 245L, 245L, 245L, 245L, 245L, 245L, 246L, 
246L, 246L, 247L, 247L, 247L, 247L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 264L, 264L, 
265L, 265L, 265L, 265L, 265L, 266L, 266L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 
269L, 269L), Date = structure(c(17755, 17755, 17757, 17757, 17758, 
17758, 17759, 17759, 17760, 17760, 17760, 17760, 17760, 17760, 
17760, 17760, 17760, 17760, 17760, 17760, 17760, 17760, 17761, 
17761, 17761, 17762, 17762, 17762, 17763, 17763, 17763, 17763, 
17764, 17764, 17764, 17765, 17765, 17765, 17766, 17766, 17767, 
17767, 17768, 17768, 17769, 17769, 17770, 17770, 17771, 17771, 
17772, 17772, 17773, 17773, 17773, 17774, 17774, 17774, 17774, 
17774, 17774, 17774, 17774, 17774, 17774, 17775, 17775, 17776, 
17776, 17777, 17777, 17778, 17778, 17778, 17778, 17781, 17781, 
17781, 17781, 17783, 17760, 17760, 17761, 17761, 17762, 17762, 
17763, 17763, 17764, 17764, 17765, 17765, 17766, 17766, 17767, 
17767, 17768, 17768, 17769, 17769, 17770, 17770, 17771, 17771, 
17772, 17772, 17773, 17773, 17773, 17774, 17774, 17774, 17774, 
17774, 17774, 17775, 17775, 17775, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17777, 17777, 17777, 17778, 17778, 17778, 
17778, 17778, 17779, 17780, 17795, 17795, 17796, 17796, 17796, 
17796, 17796, 17797, 17797, 17798, 17798, 17798, 17798, 17800, 
17800), class = "Date"), recvDeployName = c("Johnstons.Point", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Baccaro", 
"Beaubassin", "Blandford", "Blandford", "Eagle.Head.West.Berlin", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Matthews.Lake", "Matthews.Lake", 
"Port.Joli", "Port.Mouton", "Tintamarre", "Wells1", "West.Bay", 
"Baccaro", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Baccaro", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Baccaro", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Wells1", "Baccaro", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Baccaro", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", 
"East.Walton", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Beaubassin", 
"Blandford", "Blandford", "East.Walton", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Jordan.Bay", "Lockhartville", "Port.Joli", "Port.Mouton", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Linden", 
"Linden", "Clam.Bay", "Linden", "Linden", "Selma2", "East.Walton", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Cap.Bimet", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Linden", 
"Linden", "Selma2", "Truro", "Cap.Bimet", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Cap.Bimet", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Sonora", "Sonora", "Taylor.Head", "Taylor.Head", "Cap.Bimet", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Linden", "Linden", "Selma2", "Lawrencetown", "Cavendish", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Linden", 
"Linden", "Truro", "Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "East.Walton", 
"Johnstons.Point", "Johnstons.Point", "Tintamarre", "Johnstons.Point", 
"Johnstons.Point"), Hours = c(24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
24, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 14, 24, 24, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 15.5, 
15.5, 24, 24, 22, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 22, 24, 23, 24, 24, 24, 
24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 15.5, 15.5, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
24, 12.5, 12.5, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
24), Strategy = c("B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), nDet = c(20L, 
20L, 106L, 106L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 24L, 66L, 55L, 55L, 18L, 
581L, 581L, 80L, 80L, 49L, 55L, 18L, 8L, 23L, 581L, 274L, 274L, 
102L, 236L, 236L, 39L, 912L, 912L, 24L, 27L, 390L, 390L, 112L, 
236L, 236L, 118L, 118L, 180L, 180L, 164L, 164L, 84L, 84L, 336L, 
336L, 86L, 86L, 234L, 234L, 20L, 312L, 312L, 23L, 75L, 75L, 10L, 
214L, 214L, 50L, 60L, 46L, 56L, 992L, 992L, 396L, 396L, 104L, 
104L, 268L, 268L, 84L, 84L, 33L, 552L, 552L, 36L, 44L, 26L, 26L, 
78L, 78L, 5L, 5L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 44L, 44L, 60L, 60L, 180L, 
180L, 128L, 128L, 31L, 31L, 178L, 178L, 30L, 30L, 97L, 97L, 5L, 
96L, 96L, 362L, 362L, 44L, 44L, 100L, 56L, 13L, 496L, 496L, 35L, 
172L, 172L, 12L, 12L, 32L, 32L, 10L, 130L, 130L, 404L, 404L, 
172L, 172L, 104L, 7L, 108L, 9L, 9L, 67L, 67L, 452L, 452L, 49L, 
9L, 9L, 4L, 15L, 15L, 24L, 8L, 8L), detectperhour = c(0.833333333, 
0.833333333, 4.416666667, 4.416666667, 1.833333333, 1.833333333, 
1.875, 1.875, 1, 2.75, 2.291666667, 2.291666667, 0.75, 24.20833333, 
24.20833333, 3.333333333, 3.333333333, 2.041666667, 2.391304348, 
0.75, 0.333333333, 0.958333333, 24.20833333, 11.41666667, 11.41666667, 
4.434782609, 9.833333333, 9.833333333, 1.625, 38, 38, 1, 1.125, 
16.25, 16.25, 4.666666667, 9.833333333, 9.833333333, 4.916666667, 
4.916666667, 7.5, 7.5, 6.833333333, 6.833333333, 3.5, 3.5, 14, 
14, 3.583333333, 3.583333333, 9.75, 9.75, 0.833333333, 13, 13, 
0.958333333, 3.125, 3.125, 0.416666667, 8.916666667, 8.916666667, 
3.571428571, 2.5, 1.916666667, 2.434782609, 41.33333333, 41.33333333, 
16.5, 16.5, 4.333333333, 4.333333333, 17.29032258, 17.29032258, 
3.5, 3.5, 1.5, 23, 23, 1.5, 1.833333333, 1.083333333, 1.083333333, 
3.25, 3.25, 0.208333333, 0.208333333, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 
1.833333333, 1.833333333, 2.5, 2.5, 7.5, 7.5, 5.333333333, 5.333333333, 
1.291666667, 1.291666667, 7.416666667, 7.416666667, 1.25, 1.25, 
4.041666667, 4.041666667, 0.208333333, 4, 4, 15.08333333, 15.08333333, 
1.833333333, 1.833333333, 4.545454545, 2.333333333, 0.565217391, 
20.66666667, 20.66666667, 1.458333333, 7.166666667, 7.166666667, 
0.5, 0.5, 1.333333333, 1.333333333, 0.416666667, 5.416666667, 
5.416666667, 26.06451613, 26.06451613, 7.166666667, 7.166666667, 
4.333333333, 0.291666667, 4.5, 0.72, 0.72, 2.791666667, 2.791666667, 
18.83333333, 18.83333333, 2.041666667, 0.375, 0.375, 0.166666667, 
0.625, 0.625, 1, 0.333333333, 0.333333333), recvLat = c(46.2, 
46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 43.45, 45.85, 44.5, 
44.5, 44.05, 46.2, 46.2, 43.7, 43.7, 43.8, 43.95, 45.95, 46.1, 
45.35, 43.45, 46.2, 46.2, 43.45, 46.2, 46.2, 43.45, 46.2, 46.2, 
46.1, 43.45, 46.2, 46.2, 43.45, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 
46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 
45.25, 46.2, 46.2, 45.85, 44.5, 44.5, 45.25, 46.2, 46.2, 43.7, 
45.1, 43.8, 43.95, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 
46.2, 45.9, 45.9, 44.75, 45.9, 45.9, 45.35, 45.25, 46.2, 46.2, 
46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 
46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 
46.2, 46.2, 46.25, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 45.9, 45.9, 45.35, 
45.35, 46.25, 46.2, 46.2, 46.25, 46.2, 46.2, 45.05, 45.05, 44.8, 
44.8, 46.25, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 45.9, 45.9, 45.35, 44.65, 
46.5, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 45.9, 45.9, 45.35, 46.2, 46.2, 
45.25, 46.2, 46.2, 45.95, 46.2, 46.2), recvLon = c(-64.1, -64.1, 
-64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -65.5, -64.3, -64.1, 
-64.1, -64.6, -64.1, -64.1, -65.05, -65.05, -64.9, -64.85, -64.25, 
-64.25, -64.4, -65.5, -64.1, -64.1, -65.5, -64.1, -64.1, -65.5, 
-64.1, -64.1, -64.25, -65.5, -64.1, -64.1, -65.5, -64.1, -64.1, 
-64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, 
-64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -63.95, -64.1, -64.1, -64.3, 
-64.1, -64.1, -63.95, -64.1, -64.1, -65.25, -64.2, -64.9, -64.85, 
-64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -63.8, 
-63.8, -62.9, -63.8, -63.8, -63.55, -63.95, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, 
-64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, 
-64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, 
-64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, -64.45, -64.1, -64.1, -64.1, 
-64.1, -63.8, -63.8, -63.55, -63.35, -64.45, -64.1, -64.1, -64.45, 
-64.1, -64.1, -61.9, -61.9, -62.55, -62.55, -64.45, -64.1, -64.1, 
-64.1, -64.1, -63.8, -63.8, -63.55, -63.3, -63.4, -64.1, -64.1, 
-64.1, -64.1, -63.8, -63.8, -63.35, -64.1, -64.1, -63.95, -64.1, 
-64.1, -64.25, -64.1, -64.1), Year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018)), row.names = 287:436, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If you shared some code that you have developed so far and pointed out where you need specific help, you are much more likely to get a helpful response.

Comment: Hi @KeithMcNulty, sure thing! Sorry I didn't include it originally :) I expanded my question a bit and added some data as well. Thanks so much!